# Google Maps Icon is not showing on website

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, icons

I'm trying to learn myself some more advanced code writing. And this week I'm learning about google maps and how to customize it.
I think I'm doing fine, but I have a problem with making an icon marker show on the actual website.

The program I use to make the website is dreamweaver and in the live view option the customized map and icon are both showing correctly. However, when I go to the actual website, the icon is missing. There is no marker at all on the google map. I could really use some help with this one.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {

var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#0D6C91" },
        { saturation: 0 }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: "simplified" }

      ]
    }
  ];
     var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.834250, 4.309755),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('column_links'),
    mapOptions); 

  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');


  var image = '3. afbeeldingen/RLogo.png';
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.834250, 4.309755);


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
});

marker.setMap(map);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you upload the marker icon to the server?  Your code itself [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/srgw38cs/) (with a different custom icon).

Comment: It must not be the issue, but whitespaces have to be encoded in URLs `3.%20afbeeldingen/RLogo.png`